# What is an alternative to Linux utility hdparm on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, hdparm

Is there a utility similar to hdparm that can be run natively on Windows 8?

Answer (score 7):

You can download both 32bit or 64bit version of that from below links from this [source](https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/):

[Download hdparm setup package for 32bit windows](https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/home/hdparm_setup_package.msi?attredirects=0)
[Download hdparm setup package for 64bit windows](https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/hdparm_setup_package_64b.msi?attredirects=0)

**IMPORTANT:**
This app needs administrative privileges to work. After installing on Windows 7, 8 and Vista you need to [follow these instructions](http://disablehddapm.blogspot.com/p/1.html).

---

Another source is [http://faculty.etsu.edu](http://faculty.etsu.edu/tarnoff/labs2150/hd_perf/smart.html?tabid=2&print=no)

> **Note that the Windows version of hdparm still uses the Linux method for describing hard drives, and therefore, "c:" is actually
>   represented using the string "hda".**
>  Therefore, the examples
>   shown above that use hda in their command line are actually referring
>   to the C-drive. To access the D-drive, you would use "hdb" instead,
>   and so on.
>
> #### Running hdparm
>
> To run hdparm, you will need to be in a command window with the
>   current folder set to the folder where you installed hdparm. Perform
>   the following steps to enter the 32-bit command window and change to
>   the hdparm directory.
>
> 1. From the "Start" menu, click "Run."
> 2. In the text field of the "Run" window, type "cmd" and click "OK."
> 3. If the drive displayed at the cursor is not the drive where you installed hdparm, type "C:" to change to the correct drive. (This
>      assumes you installed the software on the C-drive.)
> 4. To change to the proper folder, type
>
>    ```
>    cd "\Program Files\hdparm\bin"
>    ```
>
>    where "\Program File\hdparm" is the folder where you installed the software. (Be sure to include the quotation marks in your command.)
>      The folder "bin" was created below the installation folder and is
>      where the executable is located.
> 5. Typing "hdparm-run.bat" should give you the command line syntax which may be similar to that shown below:
>
>    ```
>    Examples (for first ATA/SATA drive):
>    hdparm -I hda              Show disk identity, features, and current settings
>    hdparm -I scd0             Same for first CD-ROM
>    hdparm -M 128 hda          Set acoustic management to 'quiet'
>    hdparm -M 254 hda          Set acoustic management to 'fast'
>    hdparm -t hda              Perform disk read timings
>    hdparm -T hda              Perform cached read timings
>    hdparm -y hda              Set disk to standby mode
>    hdparm --security-freeze hda    Freeze security settings
>    Use 'hdb', 'hdc',... for second, third, ... ATA/SATA drive.
>    See man page (hdparm.8.*) for further info.
>    ```

Comment: > **"c:" is actually represented using the string "hda"**

This seems wrong. a, b, etc. correspond to the disk numbers (`\\PHYSICALDRIVE0`, or Disk 0 in Disk Management), not to the volume letters. `hda` - Disk 0, `hdb` - Disk 1 and so on.