# How to set HDD spindown to 10 seconds when not in use?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I bought new WD Blue drive and I want to spin it down when not in use for 10 seconds. Previously I used HDDScan 3.3 with Segate drive but it don't work with WD drive. Is there any other way to spindown hdd when not in use after certain time?

Comment: I strongly recommend _not_ using timeouts so short unless it’s a 2.5″ drive. It will cause unnecessary wear and delays.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by opening Control Panel, then navigating to Power Options > Edit Plan Settings (or click `change plan settings` next to one of the listed plans). From here, click `Change advanced power settings`

In the dialog, expand `Hard disk`, and specify a custom time for the given plan.

[image]

Note, the minimum time is 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the internal power management on the drive's firmware as opposed to windows spinning the drive down. You can control this with the hdparm utility which is native to GNU/Linux but there are windows packages available(I believe, never used them myself). Green/Blue drives usually have very aggressive power saving options, I had EEEPC 1000H which had one of those drives and it was spinning down quite fast. With hdparm, I was able to control this.

Check out these links, the first explains how to use the utility, the second is the windows packages.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time

[What is an alternative to Linux utility hdparm on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/857123/what-is-an-alternative-to-linux-utility-hdparm-on-windows-8)

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-hard-drive-going-sleep-windows

Steps:

Search power & sleep settings in Cortana, open the settings window.

Click Additional power settings

Click on Change plan settings for the current plan

Click Change advanced power settings

Hard disk > Turn off hard disk after, change it to 0 to disable